# For whom is Careers 2.0 meant?

Tags: discussion, jobs, invitation

I got an invitation to Careers 2.0 for my answers on the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag.

One thing I noticed: it keeps mentioning the word 'professional'.
If there's one thing I'm not, it's a 'professional programmer'. I'm a fifteen year old hobbyist. So my question is: is Careers meant for people like me too? Or is this for professionals only?

Comment: It just isn't meant for you yet.   They are trying to hook you early.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably is not meant for you.

Careers 2.0 let's you build an online resume, and it also let's prospective employers *find* you. If you are not currently interested in developing a career in IT, then by all means, just ignore the invite.

<sub><sup>Although I have heard of job offers being given to 15 y/o coders before. :-)</sup></sub>

Accepting the invite won't do any harm of course, you yourself control the visibility of the CV you create on Careers 2.0. You can keep it private and hidden if you want:

[image: privacy settings]

lead to:

[image: searchable-to-blocking]

and

[image: public-to-private]

respectively. I believe thse are set to 'private' and 'Block all messages and searches' by default, it's just that *my* settings are currently wide open.